# How could execute multiple cypher at a time in neo4j.

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, spring-data-neo4j, nosql

I want to execute multiple cypher queries at same time for the brower, how count i execute that. And i am using noe4j version for 2.2.5. My sample query was,

```html
CREATE(n:Taxonomy{UUID:10001, name:"BOSH", classType:"Interface Type", version:"2.2",isDeleted:"0"});
CREATE(n:Taxonomy{UUID:10002, name:"Iaas", classType:"AWS", version:"0.0",isDeleted:"0"});
CREATE(n:Taxonomy{UUID:10003, name:"order lifecycle", classType:"draft order", version:"0.0",isDeleted:"0"});
CREATE(n:IaaSTemplate{UUID:20001, IaasName:"Iaas Template 1",isDeleted:"0"});
CREATE(n:TemplateFunction{UUID:30001, functionName:"bosh target",isDeleted:"0"});
CREATE(n:TemplateFunction{UUID:30002, functionName:"bosh login",isDeleted:"0"});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Batching multiple queries into one is not (yet) supported by the Browser.

However, the specific queries in your question can be easily combined into a single query by:

- Removing the `n` identifier from all the nodes.

  Within a single query, an identifier is associated with a specific instance of a node or relationship (ignoring the effect of `WITH` clauses). But, since you don't actually use the identifier, getting rid of it would allow all the `CREATE` clauses to co-exist in the same query.
- Removing all semicolons (except the last one).

So, this should work:

```
CREATE(:Taxonomy{UUID:10001, name:"BOSH", classType:"Interface Type", version:"2.2",isDeleted:"0"})
CREATE(:Taxonomy{UUID:10002, name:"Iaas", classType:"AWS", version:"0.0",isDeleted:"0"})
CREATE(:Taxonomy{UUID:10003, name:"order lifecycle", classType:"draft order", version:"0.0",isDeleted:"0"})
CREATE(:IaaSTemplate{UUID:20001, IaasName:"Iaas Template 1",isDeleted:"0"})
CREATE(:TemplateFunction{UUID:30001, functionName:"bosh target",isDeleted:"0"})
CREATE(:TemplateFunction{UUID:30002, functionName:"bosh login",isDeleted:"0"});
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Neo4j Browser doesn't support that yet, it's on the long list of things.

You can use the [bin/neo4j-shell](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/shell.html) that connects to a running browser.

Or a project like [cycli](https://github.com/nicolewhite/cycli) which is a colorful, auto-complete shell for Neo4j that talks to the http interface and supports auth etc.

Comment: In case i am going to execute this query on shell means i want to modify the queries, right.